# Java Jersey use GET to return JSON that returns only some fields instead of all

Tags: java, json, get, jersey, jackson

Does naybody knows a way to use Jersey's GET method to return a JSON that returns only some fields of an entity instead of all?
Does anybody know a way to use Jersey's GET method to return a JSON that returns only some fields of an entity instead of all?
E.g. in the following class I want to receive (with POST) values for 'name' and for 'confidential', buy while returning (with GET) I only need 'name' value, not 'confidential'.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
@XmlRootElement
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"confifentialInfo"})
public class A extends B implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String confifentialInfo;
    // more fields, getters and setters
}
```

Comment: why not just return all fields in the entity and use only what you need?

Comment: I am retuning values via REST so the user will see the returned fields.

Comment: Look up JsonViews and JsonFilters on jackson's wiki

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [JAXB](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html#json.jaxb.approach.section) approach, you can mark fields with `@XmlTransient` to omit them. If you are using POJO mapping or want to exclude fields only for some requests, you should construct the JSON with the [low level JSON API](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html#json.low.level.approach.section).

Comment: Does JAXB support to receive values (using POST) and saving them to the database but do not returning (using GET) those values?

Comment: @Molly Usually you can do whatever you want with the values you receive and return anything you want, no matter if it's GET or POST. How you should do it depends on your code. I think you should edit your question and include an example of your GET method and the entity you want to return.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jackson, you can use the annotation [@JsonIgnore](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnore.html) for methods

> Marker annotation similar to javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient
>   that indicates that the annotated method is to be ignored by
>   introspection-based serialization and deserialization functionality.
>   That is, it should not be consider a "getter", "setter" or "creator".

And [@JsonIgnoreProperties](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.4.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) for properties

> Annotation that can be used to either suppress serialization of
>   properties (during serialization), or ignore processing of JSON
>   properties read (during deserialization).

Comment: How can I use Jackson with @XmlRootElement? should I define ObjectMapper to get it working?

Comment: Take a look at this - http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/